# How to make this slider smoother?

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my slider code :

```
$("#slider").slider({
        value: 100,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        step: 50,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#slider-value").html(ui.value);
        }
    });

$("#slider-value").html($('#slider').slider('value'));
```

Is there any way to make the same slider smoother without any other tools using ?

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/2986/)

Comment: Decrease the Step value

Comment: why was that downvoted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [step property](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-step), you can decrease it based on your needs to make it smoother.